# Regular Expressions: Match up to an optional specific word

Tags: regex, validation, formatting

I try a regex for the time: `00:00` with this format and limit to the 23 hours but now i want add to this a optional word: `cerrado` to valid the format or the word, this is mi current regex:

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]
```

how can add the optional word?

Examples:

Current match: `00:00`, `10:30`, `21:59`, `13:00`.

Current Don't Match: `25:00`, `10:67`, `cerrado`

and I want match how optional that specific word:

`00:00`, `10:30`, `21:59`, `13:00`, `cerrado`

Comment: can you please add some example of strings that should match and some that shouldn't?

Comment: Sure, i can add example.

Comment: @MarcoNuñez did you try adding `|cerrado` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just to add at the end of your pattern the pattern `|cerrado` like this:

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]|cerrado
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i'm newbie with regex. Jejeje